# How to use "Order" with prefetch_related to join other table values at once?

Tags: python, django, join, orm, prefetch

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='orders')

class Invoice(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoices')

class Flight(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='flights')

class Hotel(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hotels')


===================================================================
iqs = Invoice.objects.filter(order_id=pk)
prefetch_invoices = Prefetch('invoices', queryset=iqs, to_attr='invoices')

fqs = Flight.objects.filter(order_id=pk)
prefetch_flights = Prefetch('flights', queryset=fqs, to_attr='flights')
        
hqs = Hotel.objects.filter(order_id=pk)
prefetch_hotels = Prefetch('hotels', queryset=hqs, to_attr='hotels')
        
order = Orders.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch_invoices, prefetch_flights, prefetch_hotels).get(pk=pk)
```

I'm trying prefetch_related to join three tables at once.
*** I HAVE TRIED THE ABOVE CODE, BUT IT DOESN'T WORK ***

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Create an Order queryset that has all 3 relationships prefetched?

Comment: I want to use the Order table to fetch all related detail at one query. I want to avoid the N+1 issue. Thank you

Comment: You don't need `prefetch_related` when you are only getting one result, it will not reduce the number of queries. You cannot prefetch everything in a single query, a query is run for every prefetch, in your case there will be 4. It is not necessary to use your pre-filtered querysets, `prefetch_related` will handle the filtering for you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.